# How pass id to each <td> in table in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, normalization

everyone. I'm trying to pass id to each **td** in a table for a data received through API, so that each table data cell has it's own id. So far the code looks like this

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-moore-f9em3?file=/src/App.js:24-1505)

```
const normalizeData = (data) => {
  var items = Object.values(data)[0];

  var createOrEdit = (acc, key, value) => {
    var findItem = acc.find((r) => r[key] !== undefined);
    if (findItem === undefined) acc.push({ [key]: [value] });
    else findItem[key].push(value);

    return acc;
  };

  var result = items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    createOrEdit(acc, "Name", curr.name);
    createOrEdit(acc, "Last Name", curr.last_name);
    createOrEdit(acc, "Age", curr.age);
    createOrEdit(acc, "Occupation", curr.Occupation);

    return acc;
  }, []);

  return result;
};

export default function App() {
  const data = {
    people: [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "John",
        last_name: "Doe",
        age: "25",
        Occupation: "driver"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "Jack",
        last_name: "Brown",
        age: "24",
        Occupation: "it"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "Oliver",
        last_name: "Black",
        age: "30",
        Occupation: "cto"
      }
    ],

    format: { last_name: "Last Name" }
  };

  var renderData = (items) =>
    items.map((r) => {
      var key = <td>{Object.keys(r)[0]}</td>;
      var values = Object.values(r)[0].map((v) => <td>{v}</td>);
      return (
        <tr>
          {key}
          {values}
        </tr>
      );
    });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <tbody>{renderData(normalizeData(data))}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and result looks like this:

```
Name           John   Jack    Oliver
Last Name       Doe   Brown    Black
Age             25     24       30
Occupation      driver  it     cto
```

I need to pass id from API data to all td-s with the same id, like  :

```
<td id="1">John </td>  
<td id="1">Doe </td>      
<td id="1">25    <td/>  
<td id="1">driver </td>
```

```
<td id="2">Jack </td>
<td id="2">Brown </td>
<td id="2">24 </td>
<td id="2">it </td>
```

I need to achieve this so when I select id 1, for example, all td cells with id:1 will be included.

I'm fairly new to the React and JavaScript so I can't find a way to achieve it. Any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That's invalid HTML, element IDs need to be unique. You have the data you need to make decisions on rendering, there is no need to.encode that into your HTML to filter on it. Instead just use it when rendering, when the filter changes, React renders different items... That's the whole.idea behind React.

Comment: @dpwrussell, Hi, thank you for replying. I see, so how can I manipulate data in this case? If I need to select all the data with id:1, for example? Thank you.

Comment: Store your data using `useState`. Also store whatever your filter is, in this case some kind of selection. Then use the selection to select just the valid items for rendering and just render those. React takes care of the rest.

Comment: @dpwrussell, I understand the idea, but I'm new to react and I'm afraid I won't be able to create such function by myself. If it's not to much bother, would you kindly share some example?

Answer (score 0):

the way your code is setup it's:

```
var values = Object.values(r)[0].map((v, **idx**) => (
    <td **className={idx}**>{v}</td>
  ));
```

but i think you should include the index in your data instead of relying on array indices.

Comment: @ SSDMan, Hi, thank you for replying. I need to pass id from the API data so when I apply changes to, for example, id:1, all data inside <td> with the same id changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(data);

.....

// any logic that change data
...
setTableData(modifiedData);


....
{renderData(normalizeData(tableData))}
```

with react, whenever there is a state change, it will re-render, so whenever after you modify the data, `setTableData` will set new state and data to `tableData` which will call `{renderData(normalizeData(tableData))}` again

Edit: If you really really want to give all td an id, don't use id, use data attribute in html, like `data-id`, you can search more about data attribute

Comment: Hi, I just need to pass id from data Api to each <td> cell, so when I apply changes to id somewhere along the code, all data with the same id changes. I wouldn't need to click row itself.